# Function of __syscall_cp In Musl Libc

Tags: c, arm, arm64, libc, musl

I am working with a fork of Musl libc to add to a toy operating system I am building for a project. One of the challenges is that my OS has a slightly different calling convention which has necessitated changing how arguments are added to and returned from syscalls in the Musl libc wrapper. So far, this has been fine, but I have recently come across (in sockets) usages of `syscall_cp` which all get funneled into inline assembly `__syscall_cp`.

I have been trying to see how `__syscall_cp` differs in functionality from a standard `__syscall`, but the only difference I can see is the use of an additional `&self->cancel` that, if it is non-zero, causes the syscall to immediatly exit.

Any insight into the differences between `__syscall` and `__syscall_cp` would be appreciated, both any other differences in functionality and when you would use `__syscall_cp` over `__syscall` (i.e. it seems to be preferred in a lot of socket functionality).

I am using arm (aarch64). The `__syscall_cp` implementation is http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread/aarch64/syscall_cp.s, and standard syscalls are here http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/aarch64/syscall_arch.h. The harness that manages calling them is http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/internal/syscall.h.

I was unable to find much information on these implementations or their usages, other than a few things about them being cancellable.

Thanks!

Comment: [appears to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982972/purpose-of-saving-an-incoming-pthread-address-on-the-stack-before-syscall-in-mus) something about [pthread cancellation points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374707/what-exactly-is-a-cancellation-point) + [commit log](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/thread/x86_64/syscall_cp.s?id=feee98903cd8119d9a3db62589246a940f44a9f5)

Comment: ... so this should only do something different from a plain syscall if some other thread calls [pthread_cancel](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html)